# EPSG transformation just swaps coordinates in GeoServer GetFeature request

Tags: geoserver, wfs, epsg, getfeature

First time I've done much of this so I may not be using the correct terminology.
Also, I'm aware it could probably be resolved with post processing, but I'd like to fix it with this context, if possible.

I downloaded GeoJSON data from this website:

```
https://www.bathnes.gov.uk/webforms/maps/?center=51.3551348,-2.49126072&zoom=11&map=highwaysandtravel&base=Ordnance%20Survey&categories=highwaysandtravel_publicrightsofway,highwaysandtravel_publicrightsofway_subnortheastsomerset&wfslayers=mlyr-702754,mlyr-702732
```

Using this curl request which was obtained & tweaked slightly from Firefox's Network Monitor:

```
curl -o "output.geojson" "https://data.bathnes.gov.uk/geoserver/mapdata/ows?mapsource=mapdata/ows&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeName=mapdata:prowwholeroute_fp,prowwholeroute_br&outputFormat=application/json&format_options=callback:getJson&SrsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
```

I'm retrieving two layers within one request: `prowwholeroute_fp` and `prowwholeroute_br`

I'm using EPSG::4326 to transform the coordinates to Geodetic CRS: WGS 84 so it can be loaded into a Leaflet map.

If the resulting file from running the above request is searched, it can be seen that for `prowwholeroute_br` the coordinates have been transformed into the expected format i.e. `[-2.3235,51.3823]`.

However for `prowwholeroute_fp` they look like this `[167301.3397,378730.1334]` which if the above request is re-run without transformation it appears the coordinates have just been swapped.

All the other layers on that website transform correctly, it's only `prowwholeroute_fp` with this problem. I'm at a loss as to why it's just this one. Why is this?

Comment: GeoJSON is NOT EPSG:4326

Comment: OK 
1. What is Geojson's required coordinate reference system?
2. Do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: See the specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946  for details. tldr; it's `urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84` or if you want a URL `http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84 `  There is no EPSG code equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Geojson should always be in long,lat wgs84 as defined by the specification. If you want control of the projection and axis order then use GML. If you are getting results that aren't in long,lat then the layer is possibly misconfigured. Normally I would check but I'm ony phone just now.

Comment: I thought there maybe a problem with the layer.,Where/how do I start checking. If you do get a spare minute or two I'd appreciate you taking a look at it.